# alsa code to capture data of single channel only?

Tags: alsa

I need to write a code for alsa that will capture only left channel data. I have tried using dsnoop but my target does not support additional plugins. I have a alsa api to read the data:

```
if ((err = snd_pcm_readi (capture_handle, buf, 128)) != 128) {
                fprintf (stderr, "read from audio interface failed (%s)\n",
                     snd_strerror (err));
                exit (1);
            }
```

How can i configure it to read single channel?

Answer (score 0):

The ALSA library offers access to exactly those sample formats that are supported by the device.

It is possible to use plugins to create a virtual device that extracts a single channel; like this:

```pl
pcm.left_channel {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type route
        slave.pcm "hw:0"    # or whatever
        slave.channels 2
        ttable.0.0 1
    }
}
```

But if you cannot use plugins, you have to use a format that is actually supported by the hardware device.

Comment: I know about dsnoop plugin that creates a virtual device that extract a single channel but when i run arecord -L i cannot see dsnoop support in my target. Can you tell me how to enable dsnoop in alsa library?

Comment: You don't need `dsnoop` to extract a channel (`dsnoop` is for sharing a capture device between multiple applications). `aplay -L` does not list all devices.